# ActionMailer -- NoMethodError: undefined method X for MyMailer:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, sidekiq, nomethoderror

**Question:** Why is the method undefined if it's just there?

**Details:**

I have a very simple mailer class:

```
class ProductMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def sample_email
    mail(to: "me@example.com") # I hardcode my own email just to test
  end
end
```

And a very simple call from ProductsController:

```
def sample_email
  ProductMailer.sample_email().deliver_later
  redirect_to @product, notice: 'Email was queued.'
end
```

The email fails to be sent. I am using Sidekiq to process emails in background. The Sidekiq Web UI shows failed jobs in the *Tries* page and I can see why it failed:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `sample_email' for ProductMailer:Class
```

I tried to rename the method and restart the server with `rails server` but none of that removes the error. I am not using any namespaces.

**Question:** Why is the method undefined if it's just there?

**Note:** I found out by chance that the method **is** found if I name it `notify`but maybe that's because I'm overwriting some method from ActionMailer base class, I don't know.

Comment: Does ApplicationMailer inherit from ActionMailer::Base?

Comment: Yes, ApplicationMailer inherits from ActionMailler::Base. I generated the mailer with `rails generate mailer`.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:** Restart Sidekiq

I created the mailer class before starting Sidekiq, but I renamed the `sample_email` method while Sidekiq was already running, so it seems that Sidekiq doesn't recognize new methods on-the-fly.

I renamed the method because I am used to development environment, where you can change almost anything on the fly...

Answer (score -2):

It's because you've defined an instance method, and then you try to call it on a class.  Change it to

```
def self.sample_email
    ....
```

Comment: This is wrong indeed. Mailer class should not declare methods with `self`